# How to parse a string input to a DateTime?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, stopwatch, formatexception

I've figured out how to parse the input string to a date time object.

But if I input the string and run the method that starts the timer then stop it, I can't re edit the string input without getting a format exception.

In testing I input: `"00 : 00 : 10 : 000"` and then start my timer and stopwatch but when I call stop to both and try to input a new value for the string, eg `"00 : 00 : 22 : 000"` it gives me the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

This is how the strings are being parsed to a date time:

```
            //Assign text box string value to a date time variable.
            DateTime workDt = DateTime.ParseExact(wrkString.Replace(": ", ":").Replace(" :", ":"), "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime restDt = DateTime.ParseExact(rstString.Replace(": ", ":").Replace(" :", ":"), "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Is there a way to handling this type of input exception in the code or possibly an extra step I'm missing in parsing the string?

Comment: If you is working with time interval you may use TimeSpan instead of DateTime.

Comment: Your "DateTime" string does not contain date information. As Luizgrs suggests use [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{This is a comment, not an answer, but I needed to format it properly.}

There must be some other information causing the problem that you're not providing.  This works for me:

```
string s= "00 : 00 : 10 : 000";
DateTime workDt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "HH : mm : ss : fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
s= "00 : 00 : 22 : 000";
DateTime restDt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "HH : mm : ss : fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However since you're only dealing with time data you would be better off using `TimeSpan` instead:

```
string s= "00 : 00 : 10 : 000";
TimeSpan workTm = TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, @"hh\ \:\ mm\ \:\ ss\ \:\ fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
s= "00 : 00 : 22 : 000";
TimeSpan restTm = TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, @"hh\ \:\ mm\ \:\ ss\ \:\ fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Notice that when using `TimeSpan.Parse` the colons and spaces need to be escaped out.

Comment: I've tried the above using TimeSpan instead of DateTime but there is no TimeOfDay property to compare the elapsed time. What equivelant property can I use when using TimeSpan?

Comment: Currently I can use this with DateTime if `(myStopwatch.Elapsed >= workDt.TimeOfDay)` but how can I acheive the same with the TimeSpan?

Comment: @BrianJ There isn't one - a time span is a _duration_, not a _point in time_.  You should be able to compare the two `TimeSpan` values directly: `if (myStopwatch.Elapsed >= workDt)` .

Comment: The above solution worked for me and I decided on time span as suggested. In my implementation it allows user input instead of a constant value string.How do I prevent the user from entering a non numeric or alphabetical input into the text box? eg, "00 : 00 : k0 : #00";

Answer (score 1):

try the Convert class:

```
myDateAsString="3/29/2014";
try
{
Convert.ToDate(myDateAsString)
}
catch(Format exception)
{
//do something
}
```

It is another approach, I agree with that, but I think it's easier and I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know something can go wrong I suggest you use the `TryParseExact` methods.

I also suggest use TimeSpan instead of DateTime when working with time intervals. Anyway, that method also exists for DateTime...

```
TimeSpan ts;
if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(wrkString.Replace(": ", ":").Replace(" :", ":"), "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ts))
{
   //ts formatted successfully
}
else
{
    //failure
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `DateTime.TryParse` to convert.

```
DateTime dateValue;
string[] dateStrings = "1/1/2014";
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)) 
{
//code
}
```